# VSCode: SetWithCopyWarning when commands split between cells

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code Notebooks.

The following code receives a `SetWithCopyWarning` when it is split between different cells. However, if they are combined in a single cell the warning does not appear.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('my-data.csv')
df = df.loc[df['column'] == 'value']
df['newColumn'] = df['oldColumn'].str.contains('regex-omitted')
```

Has anyone experienced this behavior? Is it a bug or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that SettingWithCopyWarning is a warning, and not an error.

While an error indicates that something is broken, such as invalid syntax or an attempt to reference an undefined variable, the job of a warning is to alert the programmer to potential bugs or issues with their code that are still permitted operations within the language. In this case, the warning very likely indicates a serious but inconspicuous mistake.

SettingWithCopyWarning informs you that your operation might not have worked as expected and that you should check the result to make sure you haven’t made a mistake.

It can be tempting to ignore the warning if your code still works as expected. This is bad practice and SettingWithCopyWarning should never be ignored. Take some time to understand why you are getting the warning before taking action.

You can refer to this [page](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) for more details.

Comment: There are three lines of code.. Can you point out where the problem is?

Comment: @Alabaster line 2, This is a chained reference, leading to hidden dangers. You can try "df = df.loc[df['column'] == 'value'].copy()"

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Line 2 is an easy target; however, could there be "hidden dangers" in line 1 or 3?  Alabaster: There is nothing wrong with your code.